# Two values only showing one

Tags: php, html

I have two values in 'tipo' row as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0FBX.png) but then when I open my modal box it only shows one as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF8jL.png). I found that the other value is hidden behind the value on the image.

```
<?php
$result_t = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT m.tipo FROM `material` as m INNER 
JOIN `ocorrencia_detalhe` as od on m.id = od.id_tipo AND 
od.id_ocorrencia=".$row['id']);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_t)): ?>
<div class="check"><p class="tipo"><?php echo $row['tipo'];?></p></div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: From your code it looks like you've got while loops nested. I'd be careful about using the same variable name `$row` twice as it can cause confusion later on.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: ok but what should be the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN as INNER JOIN will only return a row if there is a non null value in both tables

Comment: I discovered a thing... the other value is behind that div but it is not a css problem...

Comment: Then maybe you should post the html you obtain.

Comment: that line is the only html code that I have for this part in my modal box